# Bind string value to checkbox checked property

Tags: javascript, data-binding, checkbox, knockout.js

I would like to bind string value to checked property. Web Service returns non boolean values like "yes"-"no" or "0"-"1" but I dont' know how to manipulate them.

In documentation appear:

> For checkboxes, KO will set the element to be checked when the parameter value is true, and unchecked when it is false. If you give a value that isn’t actually boolean, it will be interpreted loosely. This means that nonzero numbers and non-null objects and non-empty strings will all be interpreted as true, whereas zero, null, undefined, and empty strings will be interpreted as false.
>   When the user checks or unchecks the checkbox, KO will set your model property to true or false accordingly.

I understand the above explanation but... How can I change the default behavior of binding to translate string values to boolean values?

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.username = ko.observable("william wallace");
    self.email = ko.observable("ww@mailbox.com");
    self.terms = ko.observable("false");
    self.send = function (data) {
        console.log(ko.toJSON(data));
    };
}
var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Full sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/rferreiraperez/d5yb1krt/

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve here. Why would a checkbox returning the default true/false not be sufficient? What do you want to do with the values returned from the web service?

Comment: Trying to achieve what? That's not exactly a clear response.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this:

(1) Get data from the web service (I'm using literals in example to simulate this behavior).
(2) Fill form with data.
(3) The user can modify this data.
(4) Send to the web service with updated data to save them.

The problem is that the web service returns all values as strings and the checkbox is not working correctly with this type of data, only works with booleans.

I am using "true/false", "yes/no", "0/1" values, this types of values, strings types, returns always string when it's binding with the checked property.

Comment: see if that's any use: http://jsfiddle.net/d5yb1krt/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a writable dependent observable can be very useful here, particularly for conversions/validation.  You could create a computed observable that can act as the conversion layer to your observable.  Your observable can still hold the value you expect to use (`"yes"` or `"no"` values) and the observable can help convert values to and from the desired types.

The computed observable can be created using an extender to help make it reusable.

```js
ko.extenders.converter = function (target, options) {
    var name = options.name || 'converted',
        fromValue = options.fromValue || passthrough,    // from target value (read)
        toValue = options.toValue || passthrough;        // to target value (write)
    target[name] = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: function () {
            return fromValue(target());
        },
        write: function (value) {
            target(toValue(value));
        }
    });
    return target;

    function passthrough(value) { return value; }
};
```

With this, you can create your functions to convert the values and extend the observable.

```js
function BooleanConverter(trueValue, falseValue, name) {
    this.name = name || 'converted';
    this.fromValue = function (value) {
        switch (value) {
            case trueValue: return true;
            case falseValue: return false;
        }
    }.bind(this);
    this.toValue = function (value) {
        return !!value ? trueValue : falseValue;
    }.bind(this);
}
// ...
self.terms = ko.observable("no").extend({
    converter: new BooleanConverter("yes", "no")
});
```

With the `terms` extended to have a converted value, you can bind to that in your view.

```html
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsCheckBox" data-bind="checked: terms.converted" />
    <label for="termsCheckBox">accept terms and conditions</label>
</p>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5yb1krt/7/)